# adding input filter to display products, Angular

Tags: angular, forms, input, filter

I'm trying to get the **Ng2SearchPipeModule** to work, even though I have followed the instructions and declared it inside app.module.ts, as well as **FormsModule**. I still get this error message

> "Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'"

I also get the message

> The pipe 'filter' could not be found

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

// search module
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from "ng2-search-filter";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { AppRoutes } from "./app.routing";
import { BeersModule } from "./beers/beers.module";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { EffectsModule } from "@ngrx/effects";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, Ng2SearchPipeModule, RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes), StoreModule.forRoot({}), EffectsModule.forRoot([]), BeersModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

beer-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { DrinksState } from "../store";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/index";
import { getBeersSelector } from "../store/beers.selectors";
import { fetchBeersListRequest } from "../store/beers.actions";

@Component({
  selector: "app-beer-list",
  templateUrl: "./beer-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./beer-list.component.scss"]
})
export class BeerListComponent implements OnInit {
  public beers$: Observable<any>;
  public searchText: string;

  constructor(private store: Store<DrinksState>, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(fetchBeersListRequest());
    this.beers$ = this.store.pipe(select(getBeersSelector));
  }
}
```

beer-list.component.html:

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search by name of the beer" [(ngModel)]="searchText" />
</div>

<div class="beer" *ngFor="let beer of beers$ | filter: searchText | async">
  <h4>{{ beer.name }}</h4>
  <p>
    {{ beer.tagline }}
  </p>
  <img src="{{ beer.image_url }}" routerLink="/beer-details/{{ beer.id }}" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you are using separate module for `beer-list`, so you need to include both `Ng2SearchPipeModule` and `FormsModule` in `beer-list.module.ts` not in `app.module`.